# Como passar uma variável em php dentro de um link do whatsapp?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Quero criar um botão do whatsapp que contenha o número do usuário registrado no banco de dados, porém não estou conseguindo linkar minha variável neste link.

```
Contato:</b> <a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=55"> ${property.contato} </a>
```

Qual seria a melhor solução para resolver isto ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente assim:

```
<?php echo 'Contato:</b> <a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=55${property.contato}"> </a> '; ?>
```

Ou assim:

```
<?php echo 'Contato:</b> <a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=55$property.contato"> </a> '; ?>
```